Reuse partition across multiple queries with different QUALIFYs
Is it possible to accomplish the following or something similar?
In particular, what I would like to accomplish is the reuse of some_partition across different queries (query1, query2) each using different QUALIFY conditions.
WITH
  some_partition AS (
    PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY ordering_var ASC
  ),
  query1 AS (
    SELECT FIRST(id) OVER some_partition
    FROM table
    QUALIFY var1 IS NOT NULL
  ),
  query2 AS (
    SELECT FIRST(id) OVER some_partition
    FROM table
    QUALIFY var2 IS NOT NULL
  ),
SELECT * FROM query1 FULL JOIN query2 USING(id)

I am using DuckDB reading a Parquet file.

Which DBMS are you using? This is very product specific. Please give a proper example, not just QUALIFY var1 which makes no sense.

I am using DuckDB, but I'm almost certain that this wont work in DuckDB. Do you know of any DBM that could handle such query?

You can use the WINDOW clause but that only works in the same SELECT. I don't think any offer it across different scopes, that wouldn't make sense in most cases.
